# How do I find and replace text using sed using ~ as delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, sed

**Good-day,**

In a Bash shell script I'm putting together, I am trying to find this text:  */usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log* and replace it with:  */var/log/freeswitch/freeswitch.log* in this file:  */etc/fail2ban/jail.local*

This is what I have tried so far, both of which result in the error:  **sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unterminated `s' command**

**Attempt #1**

```
sed -i 's~usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log~var/log/freeswitch/freeswitch.log' /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

**Attempt #2**

```
sed -i 's~usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log/var/log/freeswitch/freeswitch.log' /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

My research shows that since the text I'm searching for includes the "/" character, I should be using a different delimiter "~" to separate the find and replace strings.  But looks like I'm doing something wrong, any assistance would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of a sed substitution command is `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` (note the delimiter at the end of the command).

You're right, you can change the delimiter to a different character, so if you're going to use `~` you need to put one of those at the end of the command.

Comment: aaaah, thank you, thank you, thank you!  Can't believe I missed that